# Weld on WebSphere 8

Tags: websphere, cdi, jboss-weld

Is it possible to replace WebSphere 8's CDI provider (OpenWebBeans) with Weld? Failing that, is there any way to simply disable CDI altogether in WebSphere?

Why would I need this? We have a project that was developed against Weld, and unfortunately we've found that it relies on a number of Weld idiosyncrasies. We're able to successfully bootstrap Weld via `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener` in Tomcat and Jetty, but WebSphere's built-in CDI implementation seem to be interfering.

Comment: What kinds of problems have you found?

Comment: @LightGuard- the project we're using as a kind of guide (https://www.42lines.net/2011/11/29/leveraging-conversations) places EntityManagers in conversation scope, which is technically a violation of CDI, since they are not Serializable. Works fine in Weld, but does not work in OpenWebBeans.

Comment: How are you obtaining the EntityManager objects?  I would have expected container-managed EntityManager to be Serializable.

Comment: @Caffeine Coma: You're right, a EM is not serializable as per Spec, (even though the Hibernate-Implementation is serializable). To my best knowledge, this is an issue if and only if you are going to passivate your beans or are working in a cluster. I'm using the technique without any issues in two productive applications that have no such requirements.

Comment: @bkail: getting the EM like so: https://github.com/42Lines/blog-cdidemo/tree/master/src/main/java/net/ftlines/blog/cdidemo/jpa. Doesn't even matter if the impl is serializable, because CDI disallows a non-serializable interface for ConversationScope.

Comment: @jan groth: spec disallows it, my IDE complains about it, and it fails to work in OpenWebBeans.  Really sounds like it works in Weld only by accident.

Comment: Why do think the CDI spec says that?  My reading of 6.6 is that a field with interface type has unknown "passivation capability", so the third-to-last paragraph of 6.6.4 should apply (i.e., OWB should check passivation capability at runtime, not deploy time).  If OWB did that, then you would need to use an at-Produces at-Resource field, and container-managed JPA would return a serializable EntityManager.

Comment: @bkail: I agree, 6.6.4 seems to allow it. But: http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html says "Managed beans with scope at-SessionScoped or at-ConversationScoped must be serializable, since the container passivates the HTTP session from time to time". That's Weld doc, not spec, BTW. We ended up using Spring for the project instead, because we were running against a deadline.

Comment: Yes, that seems accurate.  By default, your EM/EMF might not be Serializable, but the container-managed EM/EMF in WebSphere Application Server are Serializable, so if OWB could get past the stacking checking, I think it would work.  I'm glad you found something that solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to either replace or disable CDI in WebSphere Application Server.  My only (unsatisfactory) suggestion is to rework your code to avoid the idiosyncrasies.